# TypeError: unbound method deriv() must be called with NormalGraph instance as first argument (got ndarray instance instead)

Tags: python

I keep on getting this error. I'm unsure what is going wrong, can anyone help?

```
TypeError: unbound method deriv() must be called with NormalGraph instance as 
first argument (got ndarray instance instead)
```

Here is the code that produces the error. It works when the procedures aren't in a class, but when put into a class it doesn't seem to work. This is the class that keeps on giving the error:

```
class NormalGraph:
def __init__(self, N, R0, I0, S0, beta, gamma, mu):
    self.N=N
    self.R0=R0
    self.I0=I0
    self.S0=S0
    self.beta=beta
    self.gamma=gamma
    self.mu=mu

def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma, mu):
    S, I, R = y
    dSdt = mu * N -(beta * S * I) / N - mu * S
    dIdt = beta * S * I / N - gamma * I - mu * I
    dRdt = gamma * I- mu*R
    return dSdt, dIdt, dRdt

def plotGraph(self, S0, I0, R0, beta, gamma, N, mu):

    y0 = S0, I0, R0
    t = np.linspace(0, 160, 160*2)

    ret = odeint(NormalGraph.deriv, y0, t, args=( N, beta, gamma, mu))
    S, I, R = ret.T

    fig = plt.figure(facecolor='w')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axis_bgcolor='#dddddd', axisbelow=True)
    ax.plot(t, S/1000, 'b', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Susceptible')
    ax.plot(t, I/1000, 'r', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Infected')
    ax.plot(t, R/1000, 'g', alpha=0.5, lw=2, label='Recovered with immunity')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time /days')
    ax.set_ylabel('Number (1000s)')
    ax.set_ylim(0,1.2)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
    legend = ax.legend()
    legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    plt.show()

N = 1000
R0=0
I0=1
S0 = N - I0 - R0
beta=0.2
gamma = 0.1
mu=6
P=0.3
p=0.3
graph=NormalGraph(N, R0, I0, S0, beta, gamma, mu)
graph.plotGraph( S0, I0, R0, beta, gamma, N, mu)
```

Comment: could you share the definitions for `deriv`, `NormalGraph` and `Vaccination`? This code is not sufficient to understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

The `odeint(NormalGraph.deriv, ...` call is wrong. You did not declare deriv as a static method in NormalGraph. Not sure from your copy/paste if the deriv is in the NormalGraph class or outside of it. Make sure you know where you call the deriv function and how it is defined.

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful :)